# Notice: Undefined index: claves in C:\xampp\htdocs\mikrotik-unicom\mpdf\app\index.php on line 3

Tags: php, ajax, json

Tengo un problema con mi código, me aparece el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: claves in C:\xampp\htdocs\mikrotik-unicom\mpdf\app\index.php on line 3

Quiero enviar un *json* a *php* desde *javascript*. Aquí esta el código en *javascript*:

```
var array_claves = `[]`;
var claves = JSON.parse(array_claves);

for (cantidad_inicial; cantidad_inicial <= cantidad_final; cantidad_inicial++) {
            var abecedario = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
            var primer_numero_aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (999 - 100)) + 100;
            var segundo_caracter_aleatorio = abecedario[Math.floor(Math.random()*abecedario.length)];
            var tercer_numero_aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 10)) + 10;
    
           $("#textarea-claves").append('<p class="clave">add server=all name='+subfijo+ +cantidad_inicial+" "+
            'password='+primer_numero_aleatorio+ ""+segundo_caracter_aleatorio+"" +tercer_numero_aleatorio+ " "+
            'profile='+megas+" "+
             'limit-uptime='+plan+'</p>'+'\n'); 

            claves.push({usuario:subfijo+cantidad_inicial,password:primer_numero_aleatorio+segundo_caracter_aleatorio+tercer_numero_aleatorio});      
        }

var arrayJson = JSON.stringify(claves);
console.log(arrayJson);

$.ajax({
    data: {"claves" : arrayJson},
    type: "POST",
    url: "mpdf/app/index.php",
})
 .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
     if ( console && console.log ) {
         console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente." );
     }
 })
 .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
     if ( console && console.log ) {
         console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
     }
});
```

El `console.log(arrayJson)` me da este resultado que es el que quiero enviar por ajax:

> [{"usuario":"F1000","password":"583f37"},{"usuario":"F1001","password":"853a16"},{"usuario":"F1002","password":"624j83"},{"usuario":"F1003","password":"553g69"},{"usuario":"F1004","password":"716o54"},{"usuario":"F1005","password":"894p70"},{"usuario":"F1006","password":"583q87"},{"usuario":"F1007","password":"795k42"},{"usuario":"F1008","password":"133y51"},{"usuario":"F1009","password":"596v82"},{"usuario":"F1010","password":"270i25"},{"usuario":"F1011","password":"789q46"},{"usuario":"F1012","password":"975y37"},{"usuario":"F1013","password":"647h30"},{"usuario":"F1014","password":"597h92"},{"usuario":"F1015","password":"759i58"},{"usuario":"F1016","password":"551o63"},{"usuario":"F1017","password":"398l57"},{"usuario":"F1018","password":"239u27"},{"usuario":"F1019","password":"703d36"},{"usuario":"F1020","password":"196e23"},{"usuario":"F1021","password":"726n57"},{"usuario":"F1022","password":"840f49"},{"usuario":"F1023","password":"265f45"},{"usuario":"F1024","password":"114v22"},{"usuario":"F1025","password":"761p52"},{"usuario":"F1026","password":"754l74"},{"usuario":"F1027","password":"559l17"},{"usuario":"F1028","password":"804j97"},{"usuario":"F1029","password":"117k45"},{"usuario":"F1030","password":"955p69"},{"usuario":"F1031","password":"282u56"},{"usuario":"F1032","password":"996q87"},{"usuario":"F1033","password":"223i38"},{"usuario":"F1034","password":"171o83"},{"usuario":"F1035","password":"833m23"},{"usuario":"F1036","password":"473h82"},{"usuario":"F1037","password":"435s59"},{"usuario":"F1038","password":"443q55"},{"usuario":"F1039","password":"453f58"},{"usuario":"F1040","password":"372g84"},{"usuario":"F1041","password":"639w43"},{"usuario":"F1042","password":"243x83"},{"usuario":"F1043","password":"609s85"},{"usuario":"F1044","password":"309e32"},{"usuario":"F1045","password":"297q24"},{"usuario":"F1046","password":"206t30"},{"usuario":"F1047","password":"529v64"},{"usuario":"F1048","password":"852q45"},{"usuario":"F1049","password":"158e95"},{"usuario":"F1050","password":"132u22"}]

Y esto es lo que tengo en mi *php*:

```
<?php
$array=json_decode($_POST['claves']);
var_dump($array);
?>
```

Comment: haz primero un var_dump de $_POST a ver si esta llegando algo a tu php.

Comment: Si le borras los `  ` al array ` `[]` `

Comment: hice var_dump de $_POST y me da el resultado: array(0){ }, supongo que estoy enviando mal los datos por ajax

Comment: ¿La petición Ajax entra en el `done` o en el `fail` o no entra en ninguno? ¿La consola muestra algún error?

Comment: Entra en el done, el error que marca solo es en el archivo php, en donde me aparece el error de: 
Notice: Undefined index: claves in C:\xampp\htdocs\mikrotik-unicom\mpdf\app\index.php on line 3 y si pongo un var_dump($_POST) me imprime: array(0) { }